# Using arguments in scrapy pipeline on __init__

Tags: python, web-scraping, arguments, scrapy

i have a scrapy pipelines.py and i want to get the given arguments. In my spider.py it works perfect:

```
class MySpider( CrawlSpider ):
    def __init__(self, host='', domain_id='', *args, **kwargs):

        super(MySpider, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        print user_id
        ...
```

Now, i need the "user_id" in my pipelines.py to create the sqlite database like "domain-123.db". I search the whole web about my problem, but i cant find any solution.

Can someone help me?

PS: Yes, i try'ed the super() function within my pipelines Class like the spyer.py, it dont work.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Set the arguments inside the `spider`'s constructor:

```
class MySpider(CrawlSpider):
    def __init__(self, user_id='', *args, **kwargs):
        self.user_id = user_id

        super(MySpider, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

And read them in the [`open_spider()`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html#open_spider) method of your pipeline:

```
def open_spider(self, spider):
    print spider.user_id
```

Comment: It does solve the problem but it does not answer the question. Is there a way to pass arguments throw __init__ method? I'm inheriting my Pipeline object from another and I need to pass some attributes to instanciate it in the __main__

Answer (score 2):

I may be too late to provide a useful answer to op but **for anybody reaching this question in the future (as I did)**, you should check the classmethods `from_crawler` and/or `from_settings`.

This way you can pass your arguments the way you want.

Check:
https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html#from_crawler

> `from_crawler(cls, crawler)`
>
> If present, this classmethod is called to create a pipeline instance from a Crawler. It must return a new instance of the pipeline. Crawler object provides access to all Scrapy core components like settings and signals; it is a way for pipeline to access them and hook its functionality into Scrapy.
>
> Parameters: crawler (Crawler` object) – crawler that uses this pipeline

Comment: No need to apologize for being late. Adding information that is potentially useful for other users is always welcome.

Comment: Sample usage can be found here: https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html#write-items-to-mongodb